# Developing a Site Like AllTop.COM - RSS Reading Problem

Tags: plugins, rss

I am creating a website like AllTop.COM. I use Super RSS Reader Plugin for that( Even though plugin gives a widget, I have added that widget inside posts) .

Assume that I have added about 50 blogs per one page. So, when loading a page of my blog, it get data from more than 40 blogs(From RSS feed).

Is it a problem? What I mean is, will it be a problem for my servers as well as their servers because too many requests from my blog) ?

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin in question is properly coded it's likely using [`fetch_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed). This WP function will automatically cache the feeds for certain time.

Still, at initial load and when cache expires fetching 50 feeds is going to be pretty horrible and might break in different ways.

For reasonable experience you would need to update feeds async, for example using [WP Cron](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions).

Comment: If I reduce it for 15 blogs per page, is it a problem still?

Comment: @Sasa1234 fetching one RSS feed can easily take a second or more (sites out there are slow). Would you consider 15s acceptable time to wait for page to load (when cache is expired)? I wouldn't.